# Error Handling: Error and string manipulation even after error handling

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm a little stumped here. I'm obviously missing some key aspect of error handling.
I have a bit of script that *usually* works, and tends to handle it's own error nicely.
I have it set up to retry several times which it does *sometimes*, then clear it's own error.
**However,** occasionally it seems to ignore my error handling instructions and notify me it can't use some method or other.
This occurs on one of the string manipulation lines below.

```
Sub Pull_Data_NetSuite()

Dim Ref As String
Dim Invoice As String
Dim Vendor As String
Dim Memo As String
Dim Amount As String
Dim RW As Integer
Dim Chance_Counter As Byte

Chance_Counter = 0
ASecondChance:
Err.Clear
Chance_Counter = Chance_Counter + 1
On Error GoTo ASecondChance

If Chance_Counter > 5 Then
    MsgBox "error", vbOKOnly, "error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'...

Ref = FnGetTextFromClipBoard

' >>> error occurs between here >>> ...

Invoice = Mid(Ref, InStr(1, Ref, "Reference No.", vbTextCompare) + 14, 100)
Invoice = Left(Invoice, InStr(1, Invoice, "Date", vbTextCompare) - 3)

Vendor = Mid(Ref, InStr(1, Ref, "Vendor Bill", vbTextCompare) + 12, 200)
Vendor = Mid(Vendor, InStr(1, Vendor, "Vendor ", vbTextCompare) + 7, 50)
Vendor = Left(Vendor, InStr(1, Vendor, "Amount", vbTextCompare) - 3)

Memo = Mid(Ref, InStr(1, Ref, "Memo ", vbTextCompare) + 5, 100)
Memo = Left(Memo, InStr(1, Memo, "Subsidiary", vbTextCompare) - 3)

Amount = Mid(Ref, InStr(1, Ref, "Amount ", vbTextCompare) + 7, 100)
Amount = Left(Amount, InStr(1, Amount, "Account", vbTextCompare) - 3)

' <<< and here <<< ...

'...

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get, and what's the value of `Ref` when that happens?

Comment: @Tim Williams: The Value of Ref is wrong is what it is. I'm copying a whole webpage, and sometimes it doesn't copy right - When I paste what I've copied it just doesn't look right, I try it again and it's fine. And That's all okay I need to review them manually before extracting the data anyway.  - - - The error I get is something along the lines of "unable to use this method on this thing" Let me quickly try to intentionally reproduce the error.

Comment: Sorry, error is "invalid call procedure or argument" on line= `Invoice = Left(Invoice, InStr(1, Invoice, "Date", vbTextCompare) - 3)` ... which makes no sense to me. Even if it can't find what it's looking for in the string it should still recognize everything.

Comment: But my big question is why doesn't it follow my error handling instructions? I shouldn't be getting an error message at all except maybe my own.

Comment: That error can occur if rhs would produce a negative number for example. Have you accidentally altered settings to break on all errors? What's in your error handler code?

Comment: @QHarr, The Extent of my error handling is the ten lines after variable declaration. At no other point do I make any declarations regarding error handling. Maybe I'm not understanding how to clear the error?

Comment: Your "inline" error handling is not guaranteed to work - see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm for a good overview of "best practices" for error handling in VBA.  FYI QHarr is asking about your VBA error handling setting under *Tools >> Options >> General >> Error Trapping*  If you have that set to "Break on all errors" then your error handling will be ignored.

Comment: @TimWilliams  Thank you both. I will review this article, I believe this is one of the first articles I read when diving into error handling but I obviously haven't retained what I need. Cheers, C

Comment: @QHarr, Error trapping is "Break on Unhandled Errors".

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've redone the code to utilize resume(label) in an error handler at the end of my code. Works exactly the same way as before, but doesn't fail. I'll post what I came up with for future hunters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code to move the error handling from "inline" to a separate error handling section at the end. The addition of `Resume (label)` is what's causing the fix according to the article @TimWilliams shared.

```
On Error GoTo ERHAND
Chance_Counter = 0
ASecondChance:
Chance_Counter = Chance_Counter + 1

' ... ... ... ' 

Exit Sub
 
ERHAND:
Err.Clear

If Chance_Counter > 5 Then
    MsgBox "error", vbOKOnly, "error"
    Exit Sub
End If

Resume ASecondChance

End Sub
```